# How do I write small "black board" c1, c2, ... constants?

Tags: syntax, formatting

New for Mathematica 12(?) seems to be a formatted "black board" style of the former C[1], C[2], ... constants in Mathematica 11. How do I type these with formatting at input? C[1] etc. still works, but how to write it formatted? I could not find it in the escape sequence list. TIA.

Comment: You could try typing `C[1]` as usual, highlight it, and then evaluate it in place with `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`Enter`.

Comment: The actual box form is `TemplateBox[{"i"}, "C"]` so you can always copy, paste, and edit that. If you're working with formulae and are gonna send them through the FE you can do `Format[Subscript[\[ConstantC], i_]] := RawBoxes@TemplateBox[{ToBoxes[i]}, "C"];` and then use that form and have it spit out the appropriate `C[i]` form after evaluation. You can also add `MakeExpression[SubscriptBox["\[ConstantC]", i_], _] := C[ToExpression[i]]` to make it a proper alias of `C[i]` or modify `InputAliases` to give you `TemplateBox[{"\[Placeholder]"}, "C"]`.

Comment: @J.M.: That was very interesting. I did not know of the "in line" evaluation of an expression. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`InputAutoReplacements`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InputAutoReplacements) so that `c1` gets automatically converted:

```
CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], {InputAutoReplacements,"c1"}] = TemplateBox[{"1"},"C"];
```

or you could use [`InputAliases`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InputAliases) so that you need to use the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key as usual:

```
CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], {InputAliases,"c2"}] = TemplateBox[{"2"}, "C"];
```

Comment: That is so 'cool'. There is so much to discover in Mathematica, but very hard to learn (without asking on this excellent site).